# Python Elementtree filtering by XPath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

imagine I have an XML like this:

```
<root>
  <elements>
    <element> foo </element>
    <element is="false"> foo </element>
    <element is="false"> bli </element>
    <element is="false"> bla </element>
  </elements>
</root>
```

How can I do this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(XmlFromAbove)
res_a  = root.findall("element[@is='false']")) ##<- This gives me all elements with the specific attribute
res_b  = root.findall("element[not@is='false']")) ##<- This would be nice to give me all elements without that specific attribute (`<element> foo </element>` in this case)
```

Now, I know that `res_b` will not work but I guess this is a common issue so anybody has an idea what the workaround for that is?

To point it out a little bit more (copied from the comments)

I could find the element containing "foo" for sure but what I want to know is if there is a way to find any element that is NOT containing the attribute is="false".

Comment: what do you want to find?

Comment: <element> foo </element> by filtering out the attribute is="false"

Comment: you can directly find foo - isnt it? why you want to combine foo with is=false? Try to explain the logic here.

Comment: I could find "foo" for sure but what I want to know is if there is a way to find any element that is NOT containing the attribute is="false".

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear, thanks for your comment on that.

Comment: it is still not clear. Do you want to find element without the attribute 'is' OR do you want to find elements where the attribute value of 'is' is not false?

Comment: I want to find elements without this special attribute. They may have other attributes though.

Comment: Got it. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<root>
  <elements>
    <element> foo </element>
    <element is="false"> foo </element>
    <element is="false"> bli </element>
    <element is="false"> bla </element>
    <element please="false"> no_is </element>
    <element is="true"> with_true_is </element>
  </elements>
</root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

no_is_lst = [e for e in root.findall('.//element') if 'is' not in e.attrib]
for e in no_is_lst:
    print(e.text)
```

output

```
 foo 
 no_is
```

Comment: I'll try that out for my actual code but from my feeling this should work and respects the built-in module xml.etree. Thanks so far!

Comment: @goetzmoritz accepted solution doesn't really correspond to your question. Please be specific next time

Comment: @JaSON this answer is delivering a proper output. Your answer is delivering a KeyError, independent from correct or not correct XPath expression. Your answer would have been more appreciated as it is simpler but it is technically wrong.

Comment: @goetzmoritz I mean that according to your question you're looking for XPath solution that allows to get node that *doesn't contain @attribute with specific value*. This solution is not about XPath and it doesn't met your requirements as it will ignore nodes with `is="true"` which is also not what you wanted initially.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lxml](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html)

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring(data)
res = root.xpath(".//element[not(@is)]")

print(res[0].text) #foo
```

Comment: Is lxml production ready? I'm trying to avoid any 3rd party libraries that are not maintained properly (one thing I dislike about node-js btw.)